# Export Outlook Message Body to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am receiving an email report each day in the following format.

The format is the same, except the value will be different.

So I hope there is a way for me to automatically place this data into individual cells instead of copying and pasting them in 1 by 1.

```
type        ID      Date_or_Range                       Total
DAU         aaaa    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         bbbb    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         cccc    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         dddd    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         eeee    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         ffff    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         gggg    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         hhhh    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         iiii    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         jjjj    1/5/2012                            9999
DAU         kkkk    1/5/2012                            9999
MAU         aaaa    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         bbbb    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         cccc    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         dddd    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         eeee    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         ffff    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         gggg    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         hhhh    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         iiii    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         jjjj    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         kkkk    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
MAU         LLLL    2011-12-07 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days aaaa    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days bbbb    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days cccc    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days dddd    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days eeee    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days ffff    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days gggg    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days hhhh    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days iiii    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days jjjj    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
Last 7 Days kkkk    2011-12-30 to 2012-01-05 inclusive  9999
New Users   aaaa    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   bbbb    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   cccc    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   dddd    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   eeee    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   ffff    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   gggg    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   hhhh    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   iiii    1/5/2012                            9999
New Users   jjjj    1/5/2012                            9999
```

This is the ideal format, after copying them to excel using VBA.

So far I have found codes online which allowing me to copy the entire message into 1 cell `A1` using `Msg.Body` - but I prefer the follow format.

```
    A   B       C               D
1   DAU aaaa    1/5/2012    9999
2   DAU bbbb    1/5/2012    9999
3   DAU cccc    1/5/2012    9999
4   DAU dddd    1/5/2012    9999
5   DAU eeee    1/5/2012    9999
```

I think this will be helpful for many many people, so I hope someone can help create the exact [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) code and share with us.

Thanks

Comment: From the faq: "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers" If you request a ready to roll solution without own input, your local vbasolutions inc. might be the way to go...

Comment: Is it a table or just a text blob? Can you request that it be sent to you as an attachment?

Answer (score 1):

save it to a txt file (copy/paste) and then open in Excel (import wizard will appear)

Answer (score 0):

Try using paste special.

You'll have a couple of options and usually suits my needs.  It may be the 'text' version.

If you are not familiar with paste special, these are your steps:
1. Copy whatever you want from outlook message
2. Alt-tab over to excel
3. I use the shortcut keys (Alt, then "e", then "s").  That's Alt-E-S on your keyboard (no dash).  To paste normally would just be Alt, E, P
4. This will bring up a window giving the choice to paste as unicode text, text, or in the case of images, you'll have all kinds of options.

hope this helps